# Randomly accessing a file from a folder using Matlab

Tags: file, matlab, random-access

I am trying to randomly access a file from a folder using matlab. Could you suggest how to go about it? I am planning to use `randn` function, but i don't understand how.

Comment: Is your problem randomly picking a file from a folder?

Comment: yes, this is the exact i want to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need a random number with uniform distribution, not normal.
So here you go ..

```
Files = dir('MyFolder');
N = size(Files,1) - 2;
rand = randi(N,1);
Random_filename = Files(rand+2,1).name;
```

Comment: `randi` is what you want. But you should also remove *all* directories, not just ./ and ../ (which are the reason for the -2/+2 here). In the code here, you could do that with `Files = Files(~getfield(Files,'isdir'));`

Comment: That's true. I just kept it simple for understanding and figured he could solve that part by himself. Now this completes the answer.